# Alternative to Facebook Graph API's "taggable_friends"

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

The website I'm working on has a form, which includes a "Select Facebook Friend" field where a user needs to choose one of their friends.

My issue is that the "taggable_friends" method requires Facebook's review that can take up 14 days and I can't take that risk.

Is there some way to do so without using "taggable_friends"? Thanks!

Comment: The average of a review is less than one day currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop the app using test users, but once you're ready to allow real users in, you have to go through review.  While it says it can take up to 14 days, the average from what I understand is currently less than one day.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/test-user

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And is "taggable_friends" really the best way to do what I need?

Comment: @WizKid I need users to select one of their FB friends

Comment: For what? For just selecting a friend I guess you can use it but I guess you want to do something with that user?

Comment: nope, just getting the friend's name/id and sending through a form

Answer (score 0):

If you are approved to use taggable_friends, the query will return virtually all of your user's friends.  Few people have disabled tagging (at least in my community).

However, you are only allowed to use this feature if you are actually tagging people.

I haven't seen a good alternative yet.  It's a striking departure from Facebook's older policies.